# React Native FlatList key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList which renders a custom component "Card". I am passing as keyExtractor this function:

```
const keyExtractor = (item) => item.id;
```

And my renderItem function looks like this:

```
const renderItem = ({item, index}) => <Card {...item} />
```

My question is: should I pass a key to the Card component? I mean, should I do this

```
const renderItem = ({item, index}) => <Card key={item.id} {...item} />
```

to avoid my flatlist re-render components and improve the performance of my list? I have seen some people doing this... but I have never done it. If the answer is yes, why we need keyExtractor if each rendered component have a key?

Of course, if I pass a key to my custom component I will do this on its implementation:

```
return <View key={props.key}>...</View>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a unique property in your data and use it as a key. There is no need to pass the `key` to your `Card` component.

If your data is something like this:

```js
data = [
  {
    id: 'a12f56e5',
    name: 'me',
    age: 24
  }
  // ...
];
```

then you can use `id` as key.

Also, please take a look at [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration) to improve your FlatList performance

Comment: I have followed all steps to improve the performance of my FlatList but always lagged on Android :C Also, I have moved from FlatList to VirtualizedList as I am implementing an infinite scroll with pagination. Have you ever experimented something like this? (My items extends PureComponent, and I have been played with  windowSize={35}, maxToRenderPerBatch={14}, updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50} )

Comment: You can implement infinite scroll using FlatList. Please consider that using `PureComponent` is not always the best option!